# Is it possible to provide the visualization of Dasboards in ThingsBoard PE with create an account?

Tags: thingsboard

I have the first ThingsBoard PE version, I have paid for ThingsBoard Maker. With this version I can have at most 5 users including the Tenant Adminitsrator (that I am). I have create a Customers group in which I have associate a User. I have 2 devices profile and more sensors for each device profile. I have done some dashboards for the visualization of the data of these sensors. Now, I need to make avaible only the Dashboards to everyone like a site with free access. I am wondering if it is possible do it by some native settings of ThingsBoard.

[image: dashboard]

I want to show this dashboards and the states of it.

I have tried to create a Tenat user but it is necessary to provide an email and then thingsBoard ask for password. But whta I want is an open access page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make this dashboard pulic, you can follow this guide: https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/user-guide/dashboards/#make-public

After you make the dashboard public you can share the link to anyone, make sure that devices of this dashboard are also public, public dashboard only shows public devices.

To make devices public in PE version you have to make the entire device group public, if you only want to have certain device public just make a new device group and set it pulic.